# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes often when browsing

Tags: 16.04, firefox, crash, google

I have only recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my machine. It is dual booted alongside Windows 10.
I have an NVidia graphic card, Intel i5 7700 and 8gb RAM.
Changing intel_idle.max_cstate = 1 did not help my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the default open source driver is insufficient or ineffective for the machine.

**Switch over from open source driver Xorg to proprietary drivers.**

Under **Software & Updates**, go to **Additional Drivers**, and select both proprietary drivers(One in NVIDIA Corporation and one in Unknown).

'*Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.90 from nvidia 384 (proprietary, tested)*' and '*Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)*' are the two drivers to be selected. You might have a different driver that's proprietary under NVIDIA Corporation.

**Apply changes** and enter **sudo reboot** in terminal. This solved my problem.

In this picture, I have switched from open source to proprietary.
[Additional Drivers, Software and Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKR3o.png)